# How do I get the name of the main parent store in Magento?

Tags: magento

I'm using the default database dump for Magento which gives me the default things inside the database.
[image: getting magento store name]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Website: `Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getName();`

Store Group: `Mage::app()->getGroup()->getName();`